# How to create a fulltext catalog in an entity framework database migration?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, database-migration, full-text-indexing, full-text-catalog

I'm trying to create a fulltext catalog on a entity framework migration but if I do a migration with:

```
migrationBuilder.Sql("CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG[CatalogName]");
```

I get the following:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG statement cannot be used inside a user transaction.
```

If I try to do it at the seed function I get the same result. I've searched about this and all issues I found the author either decided to do it manually on the DB or some other solution that is not applicable to me.

Any ideas on how I may get this to work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Now I feel dumb. I didn't notice that Sql() function has an optional parameter to suppress the transaction :\ Passing true ended up solving my problem.

Comment: I'm passing "true", and it works locally, but not when deploying to Azure Web App.